# Multiple updates query

Tags: php, mysql

I've an update query, that updates 2 tables, one of those is duplicated with a different alias. The engine is MySQL. If I run the three queries separately they work ok, but if I put all of them in only one query it seams to fail.

This is the query:

```sql
UPDATE
    users AS u1,
    users AS u2,
    customer AS c
SET
    u1.`active` = '1',
    u2.`address` = 'something 234',
    c.`status` = '3'
WHERE
    (u1.`user_name` = 'Tomas'
        AND u1.`user_lastname` = 'Smith'
        AND u1.`user_middle` = 'Nikolas')
    AND (u2.`user_type` = '5'
        AND u2.`user_email` = 'an_email@gmail.com'
        AND u2.`register_date` = 'some_date')
    AND c.`id` = '8';
```

If I run the queries separately, the users tables update doesn't update any row (that's ok) and the customer updates only one row (that's ok too).

I'm looking forward to do everything in only one query and not in three.

The three queries looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE users AS u1 SET u1.`active` = '1' WHERE u1.`user_name` = 'Tomas' AND u1.`user_lastname` = 'Smith' AND u1.`user_middle` = 'Nikolas';

UPDATE users AS u2 SET u2.`address` = 'something 234' WHERE u2.`user_type` = '5' AND u2.`user_email` = 'an_email@gmail.com' AND u2.`register_date` = 'some_date';

UPDATE customer AS c SET c.`status` = '3' WHERE c.`id` = '8';
```

I want all of them in one query as I show you before. There's no relation between those queries, are just different queries that I want to run all at once to make improvements.

I dunno if it's possible.

Thanks for reading my problem.

Comment: dont think that is possible or even desirable, imagine reading a very long update statement updating dozens of tables at once and with different conditions...but you could definietely combine the two update statements to the user table, but I also would not recommend it, because just as you already answered youself when you said "THERE IS NO RELATION BETWEEN THOSE QUERIES"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions like `mysql_query` (deprecated!) or `mysqli::query` do not support multiple statements.

You will need something like [`mysqli::multi_query`](http://php.net/mysqli.multi-query) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't updates in several tables with one query. The only multiple update command is allowed in one table only [more to that here](http://blog.bubble.ro/how-to-make-multiple-updates-using-a-single-query-in-mysql/) (read completely to speed it up)

Answer (score 0):

Each query seems to have its own `WHERE` conditions - I don't think combining them all like that will work, since ALL of the conditions would have to be true for it to update each row.

Also, I don't see this giving any where near enough performance improvement to warrant how unmaintable/illogical this code would become. I definitely recommend keeping these as separate queries.

Comment: its not so much the where conditions that hinder that, it is the different from-declarations, you can actually combine different where-conditions with and/or and then update conditionally with case when else end but that is not really readable

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible at all, I said it wouldn't the way shown, using just a `WHERE` clause, since the conditions need to be specific to each update. But we can definitely all agree, trying to combine these updates is, in no way, an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this, I keep the queries separate!